# Multiple callback function with same terminator in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am reading data from TCP/Ip using callback function

```
configureCallback(t1,"terminator",@(varargin)myfunc());
```

Is there any way to call multiple functions in a single callback function?
Or configure same object and terminator in multiple callback functions.

Comment: `myfunc` can do anything you want, including calling other callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write yourself a helper function, which calls multiple functions:

```
function helper()
    myfunc1();
    myfunc2();
end
```

Then pass the function handle of your helper function to the callback:

```
configureCallback(t1,"terminator",@helper);
```

Comment: I think using this code, both the functions 'myfunc1' and 'myfunc2' will run every time terminator is found. I want to run the functions separately without interfering with eachother. Correct me if I am wrong.